# Adding text to custom button

Tags: flutter, dart

I am able to create custom button widget and now i want add text to this. I tried several option adding it under return container under Flatbutton but it does't work.
Can someone please guide me where exactly i can add text which i can pass to this widget along with icon and will be displayed below icon.
I can add either text or icon right now and I am looking for text below icon.

```
import 'package:tirthankar/core/const.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {  
  final Widget child;
  final double size;
  final double borderWidth;
  final String image;
  final bool isActive;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  CustomButtonWidget({
    this.child,
    @required this.size,
    @required this.onTap,
    this.borderWidth = 2,
    this.image,
    this.isActive = false
   });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var boxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(200),
            ),
            border: Border.all(
              width: borderWidth,
              color: isActive ? AppColors.darkBlue : AppColors.mainColor,
            ),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: AppColors.lightBlueShadow,
                blurRadius: 10,
                offset: Offset(5,5),
                spreadRadius: 3,

              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white60,
                blurRadius: 10,
                offset: Offset(-5,-5),
                spreadRadius: 3,

              )
            ],

          );

          if (image != null){
              boxDecoration = boxDecoration.copyWith(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: ExactAssetImage(image), 
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                ),
              );                 
          }
          if (isActive){
            boxDecoration = boxDecoration.copyWith(
               gradient: RadialGradient(
                  colors: [
                    AppColors.lightBlue,
                    AppColors.darkBlue,                     
                  ]
              ),
            );
          } else {
            boxDecoration = boxDecoration.copyWith(
               gradient: RadialGradient(
                  colors: [
                    AppColors.mainColor,
                    AppColors.mainColor,
                    AppColors.mainColor,
                    Colors.white
                  ]
              ),
            );           
          }

    return Container(      
          width: size,
          height: size,
          decoration: boxDecoration,
          child: FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: onTap, 
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(200),)
            ),
            child: child ?? Container(),
          ) 
        );    
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace your `child ?? Container()` with Column like below :

```
return Container(
          width: size,
          height: size,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
          child: FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: onTap,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(200),
            )),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                iconWidget, // child ?? Container()
                textWidget,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
```

also you can handle icon only or text only button with wrapping each iconWidget or textWidget with Visibility widget ...

Comment: thanks, that worked. Plus your visibility idea also saved my further time.

Comment: when i am passing value to textWidget i am getting renderflex overflow. If i have hardcoded value it works. Text("data") works but Text(label) doesn't..Label is string which i am trying to pass.